# How to deserialize JSON to a Kotlin class with LocalDate field in constructor

Tags: java, kotlin, deserialization, localdate

I have a Kotlin class that contains one field which is of type LocalDate. I want this class to be input parameter to a Rest endpoint (spring). When I send a reuqest  to the endpoint, in format "2000-01-01" it refuses to be deserilized to my Kotlin class. I get 500 server error instead. MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

Kotlin Class:

```
class DateInput(@field: DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) var date: LocalDate) {
}
```

Endpoint

```
@GetMapping(path = ["/input/{date}"])
    fun fetchInsurance(@PathVariable("date") date: DateInput){}
```

Whats the proper way to deserialize/serialize Dates in Kotlin?

(I also have this config class)

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig{
    @Bean
    fun getMapper(): ObjectMapper{
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        objectMapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        return objectMapper
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jackson? Did you configure it's [Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)?

Comment: @madhead Yeah, in the last code-part I posted I registered the KotlinModule